# Ubuntu touch screen problems on nexus 4

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I tried today to install ubuntu touch to my old Nexus 4 phone.

Installation was successful (regarding https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/), but when OS boots, touch screen is not working properly.

Swipe gesture are not working, when touching element, it can launch another element of the screen.

Does someone experiences this kind of problem and found a solution?

Comment: Was it working ok before on android?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem.. I bought a second hand nexus . The screen has a very small scratch maybe caused by a fall.. This has disable a part of the screen and makes UT hard to use. The same problem with android.. I could understand it by opening a drawing app and trying to draw with my finger on all the screen.
A big part of it is disable.
Solution replace the digitaizer. 
Many will tell you that is quite impossibile to change only the digitizer but better replace digitizer + lcd.
Another cheap but not full solution is to put your phone in the frizzer for 5 or 10 minutes..
Good luck